# Are there some major cup competitions not using away goals rule?

Tags: rules, football, tie-breaker

Away goals rule is often used in cups competitions and knock-out stages competition. It is applicable for two-legged ties, i.e. when the teams play one game home and one game away. If the two teams scored the same number of goals, the team which scored more goals in the away game.

As the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Away_goals_rule#Summary) on this rule mentions, there are some variations to this rule. For example, in semifinals of Football League Cup, this rule is only applied after the extra time. (Here is link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Away_goals_rule&oldid=690903205#Summary) of the Wikipedia article.)

As far as I can say, nowadays this type of tie-breaker is used quite frequently.

> Are there some major completions with two-legged ties (cups or knockout phases of tournaments) where away goals rule is not used as a tie-breaker?

Comment: There's the FA Cup. But here, the 'second leg' (or replay as its officially known), is only played in case of a draw in the first game. However, once the replay is played, and there is still a tie on the scores, away goal rule is not considered. Teams move into 30 minutes extra time and then penalties.

Answer (score 8):

The two major South American international club competitions (*Copa Libertadores de América* and *Copa Sudamericana*) currently use away goals rule in all knockout phases BUT the finals.

For the finals, two matches are played. If the tie in points and goals persists, a 30 minutes extra time (in two halves) is played. If the tie still persists, a penalty shoot-out defines the champion.